# Return multiple views to one ActionResult with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewdata

What I want to achieve essentially is:

```
Items assigned to me

Item 1 assigned to me
Item 2 assigned to me
Item 3 assigned to me


All open items
Item 1 open to everyone
Item 2 open to everyone
Item 3 open to everyone
Item 4 open to everyone
```

Though from what I have experienced of MVC so far is that I would have to return the data to the view model to be able to use it in the view itself in the following manner:

```
<asp:Content ID="ticketsContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <div id="hdMain">
        <div id="hdMainTop"><img src="images/hdMainTop.gif" alt="" /></div>
        <div id="hdMainContent">
            <div id="numberOfCalls">Calls assigned to you (<%=Html.ViewData("MyOpenCallsCount")%>)</div>
            <div id="assignedToMe">
                <div id="callHeaders">
                    <table id="callHeadersTbl" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                        <tr>
                            <td width="54">&nbsp;</td>
                            <td width="270">Subject</td>
                            <td width="148">Logged</td>
                            <td width="120">Updated</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div id="greyTicketBar">&nbsp;&nbsp; Assignee: <strong><%=Html.ViewData("UserName")%></strong></div>
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="643">
                        <% For Each aT In ViewData.Model%>
                            <tr>
                                <td width="54" class="ticketList">&nbsp;</td>
                                <td width="270" class="ticketList"><%=Html.ActionLink(aT.Title, "Details", New With {.id = aT.CallID})%></td>
                                <td width="148" class="ticketList"><%=aT.loggedOn.Date.ToShortDateString%></td>
                                <td width="115" class="ticketList"><%=aT.updatedOn.Date.ToShortDateString%></td>
                            </tr>
                            <% Next%>
                        </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="hdMainBottom"><img src="images/hdMainBottom.gif" alt="" /></div>
        <div id="bigbreak">
            <br />
        </div>
        <div id="hdMainTop"><img src="images/hdMainTop.gif" alt="" /></div>
        <div id="hdMainContent">
            <div id="numberOfCalls">All unsolved calls (<%=Html.ViewData("OpenCallCount")%>)</div>
            <div id="unsolvedTix">
                <div id="callHeaders">
                        <table id="callHeadersTbl" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td width="54">&nbsp;</td>
                                <td width="270">Subject</td>
                                <td width="148">Logged</td>
                                <td width="58">Priority</td>
                                <td width="120">Updated</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <div id="greyTicketBar"></div>
                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="643">
                        <% For Each t As hdCall In ViewData.Model%>
                            <tr>
                                <td width="51" class="ticketList" align="center"><img src="/images/icons/<%=t.hdPriority.Priority%>.gif" /></td>
                                <td width="270" class="ticketList"><%=Html.ActionLink(t.Title, "Details", New With {.id = t.CallID})%></td>
                                <td width="148" class="ticketList"><%=t.loggedOn%></td>
                                <td width="58" class="ticketList"><%=t.hdPriority.Priority%></td>
                                <td width="115" class="ticketList"><%=t.updatedOn%></td>
                            </tr>
                            <% Next%>
                        </table>
                </div>
        </div>
        <div id="hdMainBottom"><img src="images/hdMainBottom.gif" alt="" /></div>
    </div>
    <div id="hdSpacer"></div>
    <div id="hdMenus">
        <div id="browseBox">
            <div id="blueTop"><img src="images/blueboxTop.gif" /></div>
            <div id="blueContent">
                <img src="images/browse.gif" alt="Browse" /><br /><br />
                <ul>
                    <li>&nbsp;<a href="/Calls/Company/1">Calls for Topps</a><br /><br /></li>
                    <li>&nbsp;<a href="/Calls/Company/2">Calls for TCH</a><br /><br /></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="blueBottom"><img src="images/blueboxBottom.gif" /></div>
            <br />
             <div id="Dashboard">
            <div id="blueTop"><img src="images/blueboxTop.gif" /></div>
            <div id="blueContent"><img src="images/dashboard.gif" alt="Dashboard" /><br /><br />
                <div id="storePercent"><%=Html.ViewData("OpenCallCount")%><br />
                    Calls Open</div>
                <ul style="font-weight: bold;">
                    <li>&nbsp;<a href="/Calls/Urgent">Urgent:&nbsp;<%=Html.ViewData("UrgentCallCount")%></a><br /><br /></li>
                    <li>&nbsp;<a href="/Calls/High">High:&nbsp;<%=Html.ViewData("HighCallCount")%></a><br /><br /></li>
                    <li>&nbsp;<a href="/Calls/Normal">Normal:&nbsp;<%=Html.ViewData("NormalCallCount")%></a><br /><br /></li>
                    <li>&nbsp;<a href="/Calls/Low">Low:&nbsp;<%=Html.ViewData("LowCallCount")%></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="blueBottom"><img src="images/blueboxBottom.gif" /></div>
        </div>
        </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Now, the idea I have for it, even though I know it won't work would basically be:

```
'
' GET: /Calls/
<Authorize()> _
Function Index() As ActionResult
    ViewData("OpenCallCount") = callRepository.CountOpenCalls.Count()
    ViewData("UrgentCallCount") = callRepository.CountUrgentCalls.Count()
    ViewData("HighCallCount") = callRepository.CountHighCalls.Count()
    ViewData("NormalCallCount") = callRepository.CountNormalCalls.Count()
    ViewData("LowCallCount") = callRepository.CountLowCalls.Count()

    ViewData("MyOpenCallsCount") = callRepository.CountMyOpenCalls(Session("LoggedInUser")).Count()
    ViewData("UserName") = Session("LoggedInUser")

    Dim viewOpenCalls = callRepository.FindAllOpenCalls()
    Dim viewMyOpenCalls = callRepository.FindAllMyCalls(Session("LoggedInUser"))

    Return View(viewOpenCalls)
    Return View(viewMyOpenCalls)
End Function
```

What I'm wondering is, what would be the correct way to do this? I haven't a clue as how to go about the right way, I think I at least have the theory there though, just not how to implement it.

Thanks for any help in advance.

---

**EDIT**

Based on the below comments, I have made the following code edits/additions:

```
Class Calls
    Private _OpenCalls As hdCall
    Public Property OpenCalls() As hdCall
        Get
            Return _OpenCalls
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As hdCall)
            _OpenCalls = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private _MyCalls As hdCall
    Public Property MyCalls() As hdCall
        Get
            Return _MyCalls
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As hdCall)
            _MyCalls = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

**Index() Action**

```
'
' GET: /Calls/
<Authorize()> _
Function Index() As ActionResult
    ViewData("OpenCallCount") = callRepository.CountOpenCalls.Count()
    ViewData("UrgentCallCount") = callRepository.CountUrgentCalls.Count()
    ViewData("HighCallCount") = callRepository.CountHighCalls.Count()
    ViewData("NormalCallCount") = callRepository.CountNormalCalls.Count()
    ViewData("LowCallCount") = callRepository.CountLowCalls.Count()

    ViewData("MyOpenCallsCount") = callRepository.CountMyOpenCalls(Session("LoggedInUser")).Count()
    ViewData("UserName") = Session("LoggedInUser")

    Dim viewOpenCalls As New Calls With {.OpenCalls = callRepository.FindAllOpenCalls()}
    Dim viewMyOpenCalls As New Calls With {.MyCalls = callRepository.FindAllMyCalls(Session("LoggedInUser"))}

    Return View(New Calls())
End Function
```

**Calls/Index.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<Calls>" %>

<%@ Import Namespace="CustomerServiceHelpdesk" %>

<asp:Content ID="ticketsHeader" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Topps Customer Service Helpdesk - View All Calls
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="ticketsContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <div id="hdMain">
        <div id="hdMainTop"><img src="images/hdMainTop.gif" alt="" /></div>
        <div id="hdMainContent">
            <div id="numberOfCalls">Calls assigned to you (<%=Html.ViewData("MyOpenCallsCount")%>)</div>
            <div id="assignedToMe">
                <div id="callHeaders">
                    <table id="callHeadersTbl" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                        <tr>
                            <td width="54">&nbsp;</td>
                            <td width="270">Subject</td>
                            <td width="148">Logged</td>
                            <td width="120">Updated</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div id="greyTicketBar">&nbsp;&nbsp; Assignee: <strong><%=Html.ViewData("UserName")%></strong></div>
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="643">
                        <% For Each aT In Model.MyCalls%>
                            <tr>
                                <td width="54" class="ticketList">&nbsp;</td>
                                <td width="270" class="ticketList"><%=Html.ActionLink(aT.Title, "Details", New With {.id = aT.CallID})%></td>
                                <td width="148" class="ticketList"><%=aT.loggedOn.Date.ToShortDateString%></td>
                                <td width="115" class="ticketList"><%=aT.updatedOn.Date.ToShortDateString%></td>
                            </tr>
                            <% Next%>
                        </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="hdMainBottom"><img src="images/hdMainBottom.gif" alt="" /></div>
        <div id="bigbreak">
            <br />
        </div>
        <div id="hdMainTop"><img src="images/hdMainTop.gif" alt="" /></div>
        <div id="hdMainContent">
            <div id="numberOfCalls">All unsolved calls (<%=Html.ViewData("OpenCallCount")%>)</div>
            <div id="unsolvedTix">
                <div id="callHeaders">
                        <table id="callHeadersTbl" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td width="54">&nbsp;</td>
                                <td width="270">Subject</td>
                                <td width="148">Logged</td>
                                <td width="58">Priority</td>
                                <td width="120">Updated</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <div id="greyTicketBar"></div>
                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="643">
                        <% For Each t As hdCall In Model.OpenCalls%>
                            <tr>
                                <td width="51" class="ticketList" align="center"><img src="/images/icons/<%=t.hdPriority.Priority%>.gif" /></td>
                                <td width="270" class="ticketList"><%=Html.ActionLink(t.Title, "Details", New With {.id = t.CallID})%></td>
                                <td width="148" class="ticketList"><%=t.loggedOn%></td>
                                <td width="58" class="ticketList"><%=t.hdPriority.Priority%></td>
                                <td width="115" class="ticketList"><%=t.updatedOn%></td>
                            </tr>
                            <% Next%>
                        </table>
                </div>
        </div>
        <div id="hdMainBottom"><img src="images/hdMainBottom.gif" alt="" /></div>
    </div>
    <div id="hdSpacer"></div>
    <div id="hdMenus">
        <div id="browseBox">
            <div id="blueTop"><img src="images/blueboxTop.gif" /></div>
            <div id="blueContent">
                <img src="images/browse.gif" alt="Browse" /><br /><br />
                <ul>
                    <li>&nbsp;<a href="/Calls/Company/1">Calls for Topps</a><br /><br /></li>
                    <li>&nbsp;<a href="/Calls/Company/2">Calls for TCH</a><br /><br /></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="blueBottom"><img src="images/blueboxBottom.gif" /></div>
            <br />
             <div id="Dashboard">
            <div id="blueTop"><img src="images/blueboxTop.gif" /></div>
            <div id="blueContent"><img src="images/dashboard.gif" alt="Dashboard" /><br /><br />
                <div id="storePercent"><%=Html.ViewData("OpenCallCount")%><br />
                    Calls Open</div>
                <ul style="font-weight: bold;">
                    <li>&nbsp;<a href="/Calls/Urgent">Urgent:&nbsp;<%=Html.ViewData("UrgentCallCount")%></a><br /><br /></li>
                    <li>&nbsp;<a href="/Calls/High">High:&nbsp;<%=Html.ViewData("HighCallCount")%></a><br /><br /></li>
                    <li>&nbsp;<a href="/Calls/Normal">Normal:&nbsp;<%=Html.ViewData("NormalCallCount")%></a><br /><br /></li>
                    <li>&nbsp;<a href="/Calls/Low">Low:&nbsp;<%=Html.ViewData("LowCallCount")%></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="blueBottom"><img src="images/blueboxBottom.gif" /></div>
        </div>
        </div>
</asp:Content>
```

However, the line `<%=Html.ViewData("MyOpenCallsCount")%>` gives me an End of Statement expected error.

Also, I did get it to compile once, but I got the error `Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Linq.DataQuery1[CustomerServiceHelpdesk.hdCall]' to type 'CustomerServiceHelpdesk.hdCall'.` from the line `Dim viewOpenCalls As New Calls With {.OpenCalls = callRepository.FindAllOpenCalls()}`

Where did I go wrong?

I'm a bit of noob when it comes to things like this, so any help is much appreciated.

Comment: @Liam, regarding your edit : I've changed the second code example to show you how it's done in VB. Check my answer.

Comment: With that edit, i get the error: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1[CustomerServiceHelpdesk.hdCall]' to type 'CustomerServiceHelpdesk.hdCall'. But, I think I'm using the right data type of hdCall (my calls table).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once I'd worked out the correct way of doing it (a little while a go now) I got it working.

For reference, this is the way it should be done:

```
Public Class TheCalls
Private _OpenCalls As IQueryable(Of hdCall)
Public Property OpenCalls() As IQueryable(Of hdCall)
    Get
        Return _OpenCalls
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As IQueryable(Of hdCall))
        _OpenCalls = value
    End Set
End Property
Private _AssignedCalls As IQueryable(Of hdCall)
Public Property AssignedCalls() As IQueryable(Of hdCall)
    Get
        Return _AssignedCalls
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As IQueryable(Of hdCall))
        _AssignedCalls = value
    End Set
End Property
End Class
```

Answer (score 10):

Well, you can't return two values from a function, if that's what you are trying to do (the title suggests that's what you want).
Plus that's not how `http` works anyway. There's always just **one** response for **a** request.

But if you are trying to send both your `viewOpenCalls` and `viewMyOpenCalls` objects to one view, then you can do that with making your view have a model that'll hold both of them.

Like this :

```
//My VB is a bit rusty so I'm writing this in C#
class Calls {
    public yourDataType OpenCalls { get; set; }
    public yourDataType MyCalls { get; set; }
}
```

In your controller action :

```
return View(new Calls { OpenCalls = viewOpenCalls,  MyCalls = viewMyOpenCalls })

//I gues in VB it would be like this :
Dim viewOpenCalls = callRepository.FindAllOpenCalls()
Dim viewMyOpenCalls = callRepository.FindAllMyCalls(Session("LoggedInUser"))
Return View(New Calls _
    With {.OpenCalls = viewOpenCalls, .MyCalls = viewMyOpenCalls})
```

In your view make sure it's model is type of the `Calls` class.

```
<%@ Page Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<Calls>" %>
```

And now you can access the properties with `<%=Model.OpenCalls %>` and `<%=Model.MyCalls %>`

Comment: What should I search for to find out how to do that?

Comment: This is quite common, especially when returning multiple result sets from stored procedures.  I do this in my MVC application - you just write containers for multiple sets of data to return to the view.

Comment: I think this should have been selected as the accepted answer. Except this code is in C#, this is what the OP did eventually in his VB.Net code.

Answer (score 1):

1) Create a ViewData class.  This is just a POCO class with properties defined for each data item you want to show on the view (e.g. OpenCallCount)

2) Create a strongly typed view that uses this ViewData class.

3) Pass a new instance of your ViewData class, with the properties set, to your view.

This will help you avoid using magic strings everywhere (e.g. ViewData("OpenCallCount") = ... becomes   myViewDataClass.OpenCallCount = ...)

You could probably tidy up the view by using two partial view classes, or making it slightly more generic, but it will do the job at the moment.